# WPF, Flash and Airspace

Tags: wpf, flash, interop

Has anyone been able to solve the [airspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx) issues when trying to play a flash (swf) movie in a WPF application? I've been able to play the swf file using a WinForms control and a WindowsFormsHost element, and also using the WebBrowser element - but both have the airspace issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to do but I've used a transparent overlay window with success.

1. Track the underlying window's location and update the overlay window's position accordingly.
2. Ensure that you update the overlay window with minimize/restore/maximize modes.
3. Set the overlay window's Background to Transparent and the AllowsTransparency to true.

It's a bit of a hassle but not too bad.

Comment: Just tested with my scenario and you're right - it is a bit of a hassle, and it does work. I'm still holding out hope for a single window solution...