# Expander not show top on WindowsFormhost Control?

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

I am using WindowsFormHost Control in my WPF application. I use Expander to overlay on WindowsFormHost Control. My problem is When I expand the expander the content of Expander are not overlap or show on WindowsFormHost Control. All content are show backside of WindowsFormHost Control.
If any one have any solution. Thanks in advance.....

Comment: This is commonly known as _airspace problem_ and is not easily solvable. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/technology-regions-overview) an explanation as to why it happens, and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958046/wpf-flash-and-airspace) an example workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Airspace can be pretty nasty to deal with. I would consider how much work is involved in replacing the windows form entirely with a wpf form or showing the wpf content in a new wpf window.